# Setting up conditional views in Django based on user permissions

Tags: python, django

I'm attempting to set up an index page in django that serves different content based on the user permissions (2+ types of users). I've looked into using the `@permission_required` decorator but it seems a bit wasteful and repetitive to use that with a view that's been mostly repeated. There's also no good fallback method that I can see (I can't do a `@permission_required(!'jobs.can_edit')`).

views.py:

```
@permission_required('jobs.can_add')
def index(request):
    jobs = Job.objects.all
    context = {
        "jobs": jobs,
    }
    return render(request, 'jobs/index.html', context)

@permission_required('jobs.can_edit')
def index(request):
    jobs = some.different.data
    context = {
        "jobs": jobs,
    }
    return render(request, 'jobs/index.html', context)
```

Is there an easier way to hook this into the index function and change the context based on user permissions? My ideal scenario would be more like this

imaginary views.py:

```
def index(request):
    if user.can_add:
        context = x
        return render(request, 'jobs/index/can-add.html', context)

    context = y
    return render(request, 'jobs/index/can-edit.html', context)
```

I've also set the three user groups up by name, but I don't see much documentation on accessing group names.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using django permission then  you can do this in view

```
def index(request):
    if request.user.has_perm('app_name.permission_name'):
       #return something if true
    #return something in else case
```

I recommend using groups and assigning permission to a group and check if a user belongs to a group in the view
try [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/django/comments/2ro1pt/check_if_user_belongs_to_group/).

Answer (score 0):

I was inspired with that and I want to share my response too for others but in my case I use DRF and django group.

```
class ShopOrderCreateList(APIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]

    @staticmethod
    def get_object(shop_id):
        try:
            return Shop.objects.get(id=shop_id)

        except Shop.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404

    def get(self, request, shop_id=None):
        shop = self.get_object(shop_id)
        orders = Order.objects.filter(shop__id=shop.id)
        # orders = manager.order_set.all()
        # shop_orders = shop
        # order_numbers = orders.count()

        serializer = OrderSerializer(orders, many=True)

        return Response(serializer.data)

    @staticmethod
    def post(request, shop_id=None):
        if request.user.groups.filter(name='admin').exists():
            manager = request.user.manager
        elif request.user.groups.filter(name='master').exists():
            master = request.user.master
            manager = master.manager
```